# Declaring a method to accept an unknown case class as argument to use it in pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, methods, pattern-matching, arguments, case-class

Imagine a class A that is abstract and has a set of case classes. We don't know how many set classes are or even the name those case classes have.

```
abstract class A(field: String)
//Example of a case class that extends A
case class B(f: String) extends A(f)
```

Now I have this:

```
a match {
    case B(f) => println("f")
}
```

And I want to pass the case class type by an argument into a method. The reason I want this is because I will configure a set of rules in a file. And I want to load those rules and use pattern matching with some info those rules provide. I want to do something like this:

```
def printer (a: A, B: A) = {
   a match{
       case B(f) => println("f")
   }
}
```

Is this possible?

If it isn't that easy can I use an abstract class in pattern matching? It would be perfect if I could simply use the abstract class since it has the main structure of all case classes.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that case classes can have different arguments so it would be good to use something based on class A (since I can do my pattern matching with the field only)

Comment: [You'll probably get more constructive answers if you explain more about what you're *really* trying to accomplish.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)

Comment: I agree with you, but If I do that this will become a kind of a huge post. This way I only focus on the necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not like you tried it. But if you use a *Manifest* as context bound, you can make it work:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> case class Bar(baz: String) extends Foo
defined class Bar

scala> def boo[A <: Foo : Manifest](foo: Foo) =
     |   if (foo.getClass isAssignableFrom manifest[A].erasure) "foo" else "boo"
boo: [A <: Foo](foo: Foo)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[A])java.lang.String

scala> boo[Foo](Bar(""))
res0: java.lang.String = boo

scala> boo[Bar](Bar(""))
res1: java.lang.String = foo
```

Comment: "Manifest as a context bound". No ideia what that means :p. Eitherway I can't use it in pattern matching...

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `unapply` method from the companion object of your case class and use it:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract class A(field: String)
case class B(f: String) extends A(f)
case class C(f: String) extends A(f)
case class E(f: String, f1: Int) extends A(f)
case class F(f: String, f1: Int) extends A(f)

class Unapplyer[T: Manifest, R](f: T => Option[R]) {
  def unapply(a: Any): Option[R] = {
    if (manifest[T].erasure.isInstance(a)) f(a.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
  }
}

def printer[T: Manifest, R](a: A, b: T => Option[R]) {
  val P = new Unapplyer(b)
  a match {
    case P((f, f1)) => println(f + " - " + f1)
    case P(f) => println(f)
    case _ => println("oops")
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined class B
defined class C
defined class E
defined class F
defined class Unapplyer
printer: [T, R](a: A, b: (T) => Option[R])(implicit evidence$2: Manifest[T])Unit

scala> printer(B("test"), B.unapply _ )
test

scala> printer(B("test"), C.unapply _ )
oops

scala> printer(E("test", 1), E.unapply _ )
test - 1

scala> printer(E("test", 1), F.unapply _ )
oops

scala> printer(E("test", 1), B.unapply _ )
oops
```

**UPD:** Added usage with a variable number and type of arguments.

Comment: Although I didn't understand what are you doing in the class Unapplyer I belive I forgot to mention that case classes can have a variable number of arguments. And in your solution it seems very argument-dependent?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: You can use case class with any number of arguments since it's `unapply` method returns `TupleN`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: class `Unapplyer` implements some kind of "manual pattern matching". 'unapply' method checks argument's type: if it fits then the inner `unapply` function is used otherwise the match is failed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you want to pass the type into the method. When you use pattern matching you check the type anyway. So why pass it in?
You can just write

```
abstract class A(field: String)
case class B(f: String) extends A(f)
case class C(i: Int) extends A(i.toString)

def printer (a: A) = {
   a match{
       case B(f) => println(f)
       case C(i) => println(i)
   }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what case classes I want to match. Imagine that you load the pattern matching from a file... How can you develop a method that accepts what case classes you will use?